# Making adjustments to a forest plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a forest plot in R from meta-analysis results. However, I'm having difficulties adjusting the line thickness & the center points as well as getting rid of the automatic legend and creating my own legend.

```
    #d is a data frame with 4 columns
    #d$x gives variable names
    #d$y gives center point
    #d$ylo gives lower limits
    #d$yhi gives upper limits  
#data
d <- data.frame(x = toupper(letters[1:10]),
            y = rnorm(10, 0, 0.1))
d <- transform(d, ylo = y-1/10, yhi=y+1/10)
 d$x <- factor(d$x, levels=rev(d$x)) #Reverse ordering in the way that it's is in the 
#function    
credplot.gg <- function(d){
require(ggplot2)
    p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ylo, ymax=yhi,group=x,colour=x))+ 
         geom_pointrange()+ theme_bw()+ coord_flip()+ 
          guides(color=guide_legend(title="Cohort"))+
          geom_hline(aes(x=0),colour = 'red', lty=1)+ 
          xlab('Cohort') + ylab('Beta') + ggtitle('rs6467890_CACNA2D1')
 return(p)
} 

credplot.gg(d)
```

The issues that I'm having are:

1. when insert "size" into `ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ylo, ymax=yhi, group=x,colour=x), size=1.5)` the line and points are extremely large
2. How do I get rid of the legend that is automatically generated with the plot and how do I create my own legend?

I'm fairly new to r so and any help is gladly appreciated

Comment: You'll get a much better response if you provide data and consistently use code tags.  See this link for assistance in formatting your question to make it reproducible: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and also if you accepted some of the answers you have been given already

Comment: My apologies, I left out the data, it is added now